# Boilerplate template for selenium/javascript testing of an NW.JS app

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, integration-testing, node-webkit, nw.js

I'd like to start developing an automation test suite against an NWJS app, using the latest version of NWJS (0.15.0), using the javascript bindings for selenium/chromedriver.

Looking through the docs, I see that [the examples](http://docs.nwjs.io/en/latest/For%20Users/Advanced/Test%20with%20ChromeDriver/) are primarily written in Python. I'm not a native Python dev, and I've never used selenium before, and it seems like many of the tutorials out there on the internet were written before NWJS went through its big 0.13.0 refactoring... So I'm looking for some basic clarification on a few core concepts.

Can anyone provide a basic boilerplate automation script for NWJS, written in javascript, using the post-0.13.0 platform?

Comment: you could start up with something like http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-webdriver-using-the-javascript-bindings--cms-21855 and thereon maybe provide pointers(if) for the changes in 0.13.0.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you are asking for a trivial "Getting started" example in Javascript, similar to what the NW.js documentation has for python? If so, here is something that seems to work for me:

1. Make sure that the `chromedriver.exe` that comes with the nwjs SDK distribution is in your `PATH` or just copy it into the current directory. And make sure it is the only one/the first one - i.e. you are not accidentally executing chrome's driver :-)
2. Here is how to trick node into business:

```js
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
    By = webdriver.By,
    until = webdriver.until;

const driver = new webdriver.Builder()
  .withCapabilities({
    chromeOptions: {
      // Here is the path to your nw (or renamed) binary.
      binary: '../../build/dev/nw.exe'
      // Pass any arguments to executable, if desired:
      , nwargs: ["--port=56422"]
    }
  })
  .forBrowser('chrome')
  .build()

// Add your test code here...

// Admire your work for 3s, then quit
driver.sleep(3000)
driver.quit()
```

I could not find a way to specify the webdriver executable with the JS bindings in the way you can do it in python.

BTW, the [electron documentation](http://electron.atom.io/docs/tutorial/using-selenium-and-webdriver/) has another way of setting things up, but they seem to manually start a server first - that approach should work for NW.js too.